# Difference between jQuery after(),append(),before(),prepend()

Tags: jquery

I have put these functions in my code and made 4 `button`s separately for testing the functionality of each respectively. My content is not getting properly loaded. Attaching the code for reference.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $('.a').append('.c');
  });
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $('.a').after('.c');
  });
  $("#b3").click(function() {
    $('.a').prepend('.c');
  });
  $("#b4").click(function() {
    $('.a').before('.c');
  });
});
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'> a
  <div class='b'> b </div>
  <!-- <div class = 'c'> c </div> -->
</div>
<button id="b1" Append </button>
<button id="b2" After </button>
<button id="b3" Prepend </button>
<button id="b4" Before </button>
```

Comment: You should close the `button` tag with `>`.

Comment: The documentation is very thorough, accurate and contains examples, I'd suggest reading it: [`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after), [`append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append), [`before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before), [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend),

Answer (score 4):

`after()` puts the element after the element
`before()` puts the element before the element
`append()` puts data inside an element at last index
`prepend()` puts the prepending elem at first index

Answer (score 0):

you missed a closing tag `>` for buttons.that is why buttons are not showing properly.

`.append()` puts data inside an element at `last index`

`.prepend()` puts the prepending elem at `first index`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#b1").click(function() {
    $('.a').append('.c');
  });
  $("#b2").click(function() {
    $('.a').after('.c');
  });
  $("#b3").click(function() {
    $('.a').prepend('.c');
  });
  $("#b4").click(function() {
    $('.a').before('.c');
  });
});
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='a'> a
  <div class='b'> b </div>
  <!-- <div class = 'c'> c </div> -->
</div>
<button id="b1"> Append </button>
<button id="b2">After </button>
<button id="b3">Prepend </button>
<button id="b4"> Before </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.selector').after('<p>yourData<\p>')`

Will add `'<p>yourData<\p>'` after closing tag of selected element.

`$('.selector').before('<p>yourData<\p>')`

Will add `'<p>yourData<\p>'` before opening tag of selected element.`

`$('.selector').append('<p>yourData<\p>')`

Will add `'<p>yourData<\p>'` before closing tag of selected element.

`$('.selector').prepend('<p>yourData<\p>')`

Will add `'<p>yourData<\p>'` exactlly after opening tag of selected element.

[image]